# wordpress Multi site index logo image url redirection

Tags: wordpress, url, indexing, multisite

So i have a wordpress website with multi site function. The website project is made up if many different components and so i setup many sites. However when i click on the index logo, the url stays on the home page of that particular site but i want the url to re-direct to the parent page or custom url. I edited the template header to apply the redirection but the url doesnt seem to redirect. Can anybody help me to what i should do. I supposed i have to consider editing the htaccess but dont necessary know the code to use. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48094640/6950110

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell me how can you change site URL by manually and in which template?
And first, tell me how you display your site logo into your multisite?